# Thread of SDWebImage's sd_setImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

What is the thread of the completion block of SDWebImage's `sd_setImage`?

If I modify the UI from the completion block, should I always wrap that code inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async() {}`?

Comment: It calls it on the main thread

Comment: OK... I swear I fixed a very weird behavior one time by wrapping code in the completion block inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. The cause of the weird behavior might have been something else then. Basically I was taking the resulting image and applying a mask to it, setting it again to the `UIImageView` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `DispatchQueue.main.async() {}`, the completion block is always called on the main thread. The parts source code of `sd_setImage` method:
[image]

Comment: I guess this is likely technically correct. However, I still needed to call my code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async() {`, and yes I do believe the problem/cause was different but actually solved by `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. I was rounding corners on the image (using a CALayer mask), the rounded image size would be incorrect. I have image inside a UICollectionView and it's likely that some autolayout issue or other sizing issue hasn't fully sized the imageview yet in the completion handler.

Comment: Sounds weird. Maybe your UI operations needs to be in a queue task by calling `async()` method.